# Regex to replace space with dash, spacedash, dotspace, dot and apostrophe with empty strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm looking for a better way to write the following SQL statement whether using REGEX or any other way.

```
SELECT LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SCHOOL_NAME, ' -', ''), '. ', ''), '''', ''), '.', ''), ' ', '-'))
```

My intent is to apply these transformations:

1. Replacing Space with Dash
2. Replacing SpaceDash with Empty String
3. Replacing Apostrophe with Empty String
4. Replacing DotSpace with Empty String
5. Replacing Dot with Empty String

**Sample of strings I'm dealing with include double space, apostrophe, dashes:**

```
James valley court ad 

Saint's lee park school 

Harrison lodge - and  hospital
```

I need these strings to become like:

```
james-valley-court-ad 

saints-lee-park-school 

harrison-lodge-and-hospital
```

Comment: would you mind updating the title to something less verbose but meaningful?

Comment: The first replace is for 'space dash', the second for 'dot space'; the last replaces space with dash.  This is somewhat different from your bullet list.  Are you looking for an Oracle regex or for some other dialect of regex?

Comment: @JeffHolt: The original text had ".Space" in the fourth rule.  I deleted the dot in my first edit, but replaced it with "DotSpace" in my second edit.  The original was ambiguous — all the other characters were spelled out, and Chrome (at least on my Mac) is apt to add dots where I don't want them and I presumed (I now think mistakenly) that it was an added dot rather than one that was not spelled out.

Comment: Maybe I missed something in my query but the example is what I'd like to achieve at the end

Comment: I think a better title is "Is there an expression that is easier to read and prove?" and then you can introduce regex functions as a possible solution. But this smells a little like an XY problem so you might explain why the transformation is necessary. Of course, the whole question is probably better posted at the [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site or the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(SCHOOL_NAME), '''', ''), '[ .-]+', '-')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd8546/2).

---

To convert *all* non-letter characters to hyphens:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(SCHOOL_NAME), '''', ''), '[^a-z]+', '-')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd8546/4).

---

Both options produce the following from your input:

```
james-valley-court-ad
saints-lee-park-school
harrison-lodge-and-hospital
```

Comment: Very helpful and much appreciated :)